# Microservices in Docker/Kubernetes to achieve code reusability in an organization

Tags: git, docker, kubernetes, microservices, reusability

I am working with an organization for some time as a freelancer. This organization develop webs/apps for different clients. So every web and app is different. Most of their web portals follow the same UI structure but obviously the data/fields and a lot of navigation and workflow etc is different for each client (login and forgot password is what is very similar for each client). They write most of the backend in Node(Express) and use Mongodb as default database for every project. But clients regularly come up with existing systems that use different databases like Postgresql or MySQL etc.

Recently a casual discussion came up about how to develop re-usable code that can speed up the development of new projects. I gave the following suggestions:

> 1. Developers writing code should keep re-usability in mind and there
>    should be a github repo for each platform (nodejs, java, php etc)
>    where developer can push re-usable code. For example I have a lot of
>    re-usable php and js files to integrate with 3rd party libraries like
>    mailgun , sendgrid etc. I can push these files in respective repos and
>    if another developer is working on same thing they can just simply
>    pull the files from the repo and use in their project..they just have
>    to pass the correct credentials to the functions and the job is done.
> 2. A simple html/css based template for Admin/Web portals that
>    consists of common components like header bar , side navigation ,
>    tables etc. Anyone starting a new web portal will pull this template
>    from the repo and start developing. In case they develop some web
>    component that is re-usable and common for other portals ..they can
>    push that component separately in a repo.

Another developer came up with the following:

[image]

I understand that docker and/or kubernetes makes deployment very simple. But I am not at all convinced personally that this architecture can be followed for code-reusability. But I said to myself that it is highly likely that I am not seeing something that the other developer see. Keeping in mind that requirements for each client will be totally different...few parts can be common like I said login/forgot password in web portals are very similar. But these microservices will not be hosted anywhere centrally instead they will be deployed on each client site.

I have a lot of questions on my mind regarding this architecture for code-reusability but I would like to get the opinions of developers here on stackoverflow for better clarity.

So my goal for this question is to get the opinion of other developers about the Microservices (deployed on each client's site) architecture for code re-usability.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to say anything for sure before knowing the existing setup and requirements.

if you are talking about moving from some sort of monolith to microservices just for the sake of sharing some utility code I would say think again.
Microservices is a lot harder to test , deploy and maintain comparing to a monolith architecture. Let alone doing it just for code reusability doesn't make any sense to me personally.

Having said that if you have some scalability issues in terms of performance of the system or development and would like to extract different **domains** -which is nothing to do with code reusability- into its own microservices it could be considered.

Lastly to really benefit from a distributed architecture your first concern shouldn't be the code reusability. It is simply not worth it considering the changes you should make in your development, testing and maintenance step.

Comment: Hi cool, thank you for your response. The main problem because of which I wanted to resist this architecture is that as I mentioned we don't have any base monolith application that we want to scale or convert. It is a software sol. company and we keep developing different systems for different clients. Our goal is code-reusability whenever we are starting new project to speed up development.

Comment: Are you providing your solution as saas or deployment packages

Comment: If you are providing them as SaaS then that architecture could make sense. Otherwise asking the client managing such distributed architecture wouldn't be welcomed. I wouldn't want to have such a solution if I will be responsible from keeping it up an running as I know what it takes to do it right.

Comment: For example if you are our client you will come to us with your requirements for a website or a mobile app...we will develop the website and/or mobile app and deliver it to you...deployment is our responsibility but we will deploy everything on your provided site. Then another client will come with totally different requirements for their website and/or mobile app and we do the same.

Comment: are you already providing your clients a whole kubernetes cluster with components?

Comment: no we are not. For example if we develop a nodejs backend ... we just simply deploy the app without kubernetes cluster. Honestly working for some time with them I never felt a need to go for kubernetes..as all of the systems we developed were monolith and they in my opinion must be monolith for simplicity and easy maintenance.

Comment: Kubernetes cluster is a proposed architecture going forward

Comment: Oh man then forget about it. Kubernetes itself is quite complicated to setup and run. To be able to maintain it your client should have a specific resource like an experienced dev-ops etc. I guess unless they have such an infrastructure ready they would not accept such solution.